# Can I make pip installable package without registering package in pypi?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, packaging, pypi

I'm trying to make pip installable package with python3 following the description in : [Url here](https://marthall.github.io/blog/how-to-package-a-python-app/)

I successfully install my package using `sudo python setup.py install` , however `pip install mypackage` doesn't work. Is that because I didn't register/ upload my package to PyPI? (As it's an internal project for my work I'm not allowed to upload the package in PyPI. )

Answer (score 2):

From [pip's user guide](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#installing-packages):

> pip supports installing from PyPI, version control, local projects,
>   and directly from distribution files.

The command-line to use is different:

There is a suitable command-line use for each of them and pip looks for, in the following order:

When looking at the items to be installed, pip checks what type of item each is, in the following order:

> 1. Project or archive URL.
> 2. Local directory (which must contain a setup.py, or pip will report an error).
> 3. Local file (a sdist or wheel format archive, following the naming conventions for those formats).
> 4. A requirement, as specified in PEP 440.

For your specific problem, you don't need to upload to PyPI. Solutions:

1. Build a "wheel" https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_wheel/ and distribute that file, pip can install it.
2. Place a zip archive of the source somewhere on your intranet (or shared file system) and call `pip install http://intranet.url/mypackage-1.0.4.zip`

Comment: Hi there, could you tell what actually you need to place in the .zip file in order to be able to install it? Is it is just the wheel file?

Comment: The full source with the setup.py file at the root level of the zip archive.