# can I create python package with no publishing to pypi?

Tags: python, package, pypi

following this guide: https://realpython.com/pypi-publish-python-package/
can I just create my Python package but not publish it to pypi.
just install it with pip install and then import my_packeg.
when trying this get No module named my_packeg error
the goal is to using this package code inside x micro service for prevent duplicate code...

Comment: yes, you can use `pip install` to a install a local `.whl` file

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67531834/3797285

Answer (score 0):

From pip's user guide:

pip supports installing from PyPI, version control, local projects, and directly from distribution files.

The command-line to use is different:

There is a suitable command-line use for each of them and pip looks for, in the following order:

When looking at the items to be installed, pip checks what type of item each is, in the following order:

Project or archive URL.
Local directory (which must contain a setup.py, or pip will report an error).
Local file (a sdist or wheel format archive, following the naming conventions for those formats).
A requirement, as specified in PEP 440.
For your specific problem, you don't need to upload to PyPI. Solutions:

Build a "wheel" https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_wheel/ and distribute that file, pip can install it.
Place a zip archive of the source somewhere on your intranet (or shared file system) and call pip install http://intranet.url/mypackage-1.0.4.zip

**source: [Can I make pip installable package without registering package in pypi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48169424/can-i-make-pip-installable-package-without-registering-package-in-pypi)**